# Dynamic Meta Image with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble binding the current value of the currently selected image in my single-page angular app to populate the  tag src attribute.

Below is what I have so far, which works fine using ng-bind on the title tag.

**Index.html**

```
<title ng-bind="$state.$current.locals.globals.pageTitle"></title>
```

Even though it's a bit janky, the title above renders fine.

The problem is with this line in index.html, i can't get the previewImage value to be properly bound to the link rel 'src' attribute.

```
  <link rel="image_src"  ng-attr-src="$state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage" />
```

**App.js**

```
  run.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope','$state', '$stateParams'];

  function run($http, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $rootScope.currentboard_id = 0;
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $rootScope.previewImage = $state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage;
  }
```

**Router**

```
 $stateProvider.state('modal', {
  url: '/post/:post_id',
  template: '<div ui-view="modal"></div>',
  resolve: {
    post: ['Posts', '$stateParams', function(Posts, $stateParams) {
      // Use Posts service to retrieve a title
      return Posts.get_post($stateParams.post_id);
  }],
    // Dynamic title showing the name of post
    pageTitle: ['post','$stateParams', function(post,$stateParams) {
      return post.data['0'].description;
  }],
     // Dynamic title showing the name of post
    previewImage: ['post','$stateParams', function(post,$stateParams) {
      // hack to get image urls from image tags
      var m,
      urls = [], 
      str = post.data['0'].image,
      rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/g;

      while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
        urls.push( m[1] );
      }

      return urls; 
  }]
  },
  onEnter: showModal
})
```

Comment: You could try <link rel="image_src"  src="{{ $state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage }}" />

Comment: I get an error, Could not parse the remainder: '$state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage' from '$state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage'

Comment: Are you using django as well? console.log the urls variable in the previewImage function before returning it. Make sure it is filled.

Comment: Yes, the variable is filled, i tracked it down to an conflict with django variable tags, so i tried this, still no luck though
  [code]{%verbatim%}
  <link rel="image_src"  src="{{ $state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage }}" />
  {%endverbatim%}[/code]

Comment: and are you using django templates by chance?

Comment: Yes ok - its a django issue. Suggest you add a django tag to this post.

Comment: This actually solved it upon second try

Answer (score 0):

```
  {%verbatim%}
  <meta property="og:title" ng-attr-content="{{ $state.$current.locals.globals.pageTitle }}"/>
  <meta property="og:image" ng-attr-content="{{ $state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage }}" />
  <link rel="image_src" href="{{ $state.$current.locals.globals.previewImage }}" />
  {%endverbatim%}
```